# How do I deploy my apps script into my google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a google apps script which sorts 2 columns in a sheet and I want it to always be running when the sheet is updated by a jotform submission. The script works fine when i test it but I've tried to 'deploy' it into the sheet without success.
I tried to deploy it as a web-app and and add-on but am not sure if they're the correct type of 'deployment'. Is there another step I'm missing to make my script 'go live'?
Some guidance on this would be appreciated. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJUjC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but I think you mean you want your function to be called from within a cell? An example from Google's documentation is as follows:

#1: Create and name your function:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

#2 Then write the function directly into the cell as you would with =SUM():

```
=DOUBLE(A1)
```

If this is (and sorry if it isn't) what you're trying to do, then you don't need to deploy the script or anything extra like that. Just save it and it should start to work.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Thanks. It seemed I was overthinking things by asking how to "deploy" apps and you inadvertently pointed me on the right track. In case anyone runs into the same problem I found the answer I was looking for here--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsIOcz4m7lM

Comment: Great. Glad I was of some help!